# PHP выдаёт ошибку, при использование self:: в mysqli запросах

Tags: php, mysqli

Пытаюсь выполнить запрос:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query(self::$dbc, "SELECT `fname` FROM `people` WHERE `user_id` = self::$id"));
```

Говорит, что не определена переменная `id`

Хотя код:

```
$test = self::$id;
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query(self::$dbc, "SELECT fname FROM people WHERE user_id = '$test'"));
```

работает.

Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

интерпретатор распознает **self** как часть строки, а не зарезервированное слово, поэтому пытается просто обратиться к переменной **$id** которой не существует

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query(self::$dbc, "SELECT `fname` FROM `people` WHERE `user_id` = ".self::$id));
```